# Onclick refresh only div content, Not all aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two pages that inherit from one master page, First.aspx or second.aspx. Navigation is on master page. If I am on first.aspx page & want to go to second.aspx onClick. I just want to load My contentplaceholder, not refresh all of the page. Is this possible or not?How do I do this if it is possible?

I have tried using:

```
$(function() { $("#btn").click(function() {
   $("#Content").load("Second.aspx");
   }); 
});
```

I have also tried using this:

```
function SelectRol() {
   window.location = 'Second.aspx';
   return false;
}
```

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not going to work. You could use ASP.Net UpdatePanel for partial page refreshing, or better use JQuery Ajax methods to load HTML content you want to show.

See http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1123-partial-page-refresh-using-jquery.aspx for more information about this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use ajax call if you don't want whole page to get refreshed . or you can use AHAH as the one facebook use for the chat box

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as Partial Loading / Partial postback. We can only do Partial Rendering. If you need to load a second page that page's entire page event life cycle would happen which will include the Master page's events.

If you need a true Ajax mechanism. Render your scripts initially which will construct your UI and subsequent communication will be transmitting only the data using RESTful / JSON service.